# How to compare custom sql field in condition using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a sql table which field are qustionid, question, answer, message-type . i am generate dynamic label text through c#.
how to compare message-type field value on c# if else condition.

my code is-

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    string spName = @"dbo.[spUserResponseTest]";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserRequest", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
    
                  
    
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {

            if (message-type == "text")
            {
                // message customize
            }
            string html = "<ul>";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string bot_respons_list = String.Format("{0}", reader["Answer"]);
                html += "<li>" + bot_respons_list + "</li>";
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare, you first need to put your condition inside while (reader.Read()){} . then add the column number of your table to reader[].toString() in your if-else condition. learn more about Database adapters before you do these!

you have not specified which platform you're on!

```
while (reader.Read())
{
 if (reader["*COLUMN NUMBER FOR message-type*"].toString() == "text")
    {
      // message customize
    }
  //other functions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the rest of your code. But if message-type from `(message-type == "text")` should be from a field from your reader and you want to check it, then just write
`if (reader["message-type"].ToString() == "text")`